# Counting Cells with date enter as MM/DD/YYYY, but formatted as Month-YY

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a document that shows users who have accounts for a company resource, and it shows their last login.  The exported data into excel shows as Last Login (Column E) and the cell data is MM/DD/YYYY with a time stamp. Example: 4/15/2015  3:01:59 PM

I have formatted all the cells to read as Month-YY. So that example shows April-15.

I am trying to make a chart to show how many users last logged in by counting the dates. So say 10 people last logged in April-15, and 20 people in June-15.

I have this formula I am trying to use, Table1[Last Login] is column E.

=COUNTIF(Table1[Last Login],"*April-15*")

That returns 0.

The issue I am running into is the formula is looking at the data in the cell as 4/15/2015  3:01:59 PM, rather than what I formatted it to, April-15. I have a little VB experience, but its been a while since school.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest trimming the time from the date. Regardless, the formatting you applied is purely cosmetic. Excel will still use the actual date, not the formatted date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will count all the dates in month of april of 2015:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Last Login]) = 2015)*(MONTH(Table1[Last Login])=4))
```

You can substitute the hard coded numbers to a cell reference.  If you put the date in say G1 then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Last Login]) = YEAR(G1))*(MONTH(Table1[Last Login])=MONTH(G1)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked out perfect! I used the second formula referencing a cell.

Comment: @MichaelCrane please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.